# Mixed partial derivatives are different

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be defined as

$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} x_1^2 \operatorname{arctan} \left( \frac{x_2}{x_1} \right) - x_2^2 \operatorname{arctan} \left( \frac{x_1}{x_2} \right), & x_1 x_2 \neq 0, \\
0, & x_1 x_2 = 0. \end{matrix} \right.$$

Notation: $D_j f$ means the partial derivative with respect to the $j$-th coordinate.

I have shown that $D_2 D_1 f(0) \neq D_1 D_2 f(0)$.

**My question**: we know $f(x) = 0$ whenever $x_1 = 0$ or $x_2 = 0$. This implies that $D_1 f(0) = D_2 f(0) = 0$ applying the definition. **However, would this mean that $D_1 f(x)$ or $D_2 f(x)$ equals zero whenever $x_1 = 0$ or $x_2 = 0$, in the inclusive sense of "or"?**

I have used that $D_i f$ is not necessarily zero unless at the origin to show that the mixed partials are different. The expressions for them are

$$\begin{align}
D_1 f(x) & = 2x_1 \operatorname{arctan} \left( \frac{x_2}{x_1} \right) - x_2, \\
D_2 f(x) & = x_1 - 2x_2 \operatorname{arctan} \left( \frac{x_1}{x_2} \right).
\end{align}$$

Applying the definition again to this I found $D_2 D_1 f(0) = -1$ and $D_1 D_2 f(0) = 1$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the fact that $f(x) = 0$ at the origin does not imply anything about the local behavior of the function. How has this led you to conclude that the partial derivatives are $0$ there?

Comment: The function $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) =x$ is such that $f(x) = 0$ when $x = 0$; however, this does not imply that $f'(0) = 0$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A or B whenever C or D" is a confusing statement. Let's keep things sorted:

- If $f(x_1,0)=0$ for all $x_1$, then    $D_1 f(x_1,0) = 0$ for all $x_1$. Indeed, once $x_2$ is fixed at $0$, we have a function of $x_1$ only, which happens to be  identically zero. Thus, its derivative  is identically zero too.
- Similarly: if $f(0,x_2)=0$ for all $x_2$, then $D_2 f(0,x_2)=0$ for all $x_2$.

On the other hand,

- having  $f(x_1,0)=0$ for all $x_1$ does **not** imply    $D_2 f(x_1,0) = 0$.
- having  $f(0,x_2)=0$ for all $x_2$ does **not** imply    $D_1 f(0,x_2 ) = 0$.

In both cases, the simple function $x_1x_2$ is a counterexample.